# Can I speed this query up without storing the group by and order by value?

Tags: mysql, database-design, query-optimization

I have the following query:

```
SELECT IF(dissolution_date IS NULL,
          YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(incorporation_date),
          YEAR(dissolution_date) - YEAR(incorporation_date)) as length,
   COUNT(DISTINCT(id_company)) as count
FROM company
WHERE incorporation_date IS NOT NULL
GROUP BY length
ORDER BY length ASC
```

Given that I have the dissolution date (or a replacement for it) and the incorporation date it seems redundant to add an additional column to the table which stores the difference between the two dates (especially as if a company hasn't dissolved, the dissolution date would need updating every <strike>day</strike> year).

The EXPLAIN output is as follows:

```
 id | select_type | table   | type | possible_keys      | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra
----|-------------|---------|------|--------------------|------|---------|------|----------------------------------------
 1  | SIMPLE      | company | ALL  | incorporation_date | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 9128995 | Using where; Using filesort
```

and currently the query takes 10's of seconds, whereas similar queries on non-calculated columns take milliseconds, which is what I'd like to achieve here.

Is it possible to group and order by length without using filesort and without adding the length column to the original table? Or should I just add the length column in, in which case what would be the best way of updating the dissolution_date every <strike>day</strike> year?

Comment: What about replacing the `IF( ... )` with `YEAR(COALESCE(dissolution_date, CURDATE())) - YEAR(incorporation_date) AS length`

Comment: Thanks for the heads-up re: COALESCE, but it didn't make any difference :(

Comment: What's the use of `COUNT(DISTINCT id_company)`? Isn't the `id_company` the PK? If yes, you could replace that with `COUNT(*)`

Comment: @ypercube good shout, not sure I've completely got my head wrapped around when to use DISTINCT COUNTS and when to use COUNT(*)

Comment: One more thing. In MysQL, the `GROUP BY length ORDER BY length ASC` can be shortened to `GROUP BY length ASC` with guarenteed same results (and usually better performance). You can actually skip the `ASC` too but I prefer it there to identify to any future code reader what the query is supposed to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are referring to in Database theory is called a derived attribute. You do not want to implement such an attribute because although it will work fast, it's not very accurate. So we dont create a column for such an attribute but rather calculate it when needed.

There is no need for the file sorting, it's what the order by clause is doing.

Assuming that your query is correct, I would suggest creating a B Tree index on the company table using search key attributes (dissolution_date, incorporation_date) since they appear to be heavily used in your query.

Could you give an idea of the company table?

Comment: However, I'm getting `Using where; Using index; Using temporary; Using filesort` when I `EXPLAIN` the query... it does use the new key (of length 4) but I'd like to get it to stop filesorting if possible

Comment: Also could you expand on "Assuming your query is correct" please?

Comment: well an index is created for a specific query so: assuming the query is correct